# Why is some fetched data undefined and other data fetched is not undefined?

Tags: reactjs, axios

Im fetching data from the Google Custom search API and for some reason i´m being able to access some properties of the object and others not.

Search.js:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import Searchbar from '../molecules/Searchbar'
import { useState } from 'react';
import Item from '../molecules/Item';


const Search = () => {    
  
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
  const [resultData, setResultData] = useState({});
  const [loading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  
  
 function searchInGoogle(e){
    
    const BASE_URL = `https://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1`
    const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_SEARCH_KEY;
    const SEARCH_ENGINE_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_SEARCH_ENGINE_KEY;    
    var apiCall = `${BASE_URL}?key=${API_KEY}&cx=${SEARCH_ENGINE_KEY}&q=${searchText}`

    axios.get(apiCall).then(function (response){
      setIsLoading(true)
      console.log(response.data)
      setResultData(response.data)
      setIsLoading(false)

    }).catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
      setIsLoading(false)
    })
    
  }

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setSearchText(e.target.value)
  }
  
  const items = resultData.items?.map((item)=>{
    return <Item key={item.id} title={item.title} description={item.htmlSnippet}/>
      
      
    }) ?? [] // return an empty array in case the result is undefined
    
  
    

  return (
    <div>
      <input className='searchInput' onChange={handleInputChange} ></input>
      <button className='btn' onClick={searchInGoogle} >Submit</button>
      {/* <Searchbar /> */}
      <div>
        {<p>{resultData.searchInformation.formattedTotalResults}</p>  }

        {
        
        (resultData.items && Object.keys(resultData.items)) !== 0 ? <>
        {items}

        </> : <><p>No results</p></>
        }

      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Search
```

The data that i´m getting using axios is stored in `resultData` and i made a `loading` state so that the value changes before and after the data is being fetched.

If you can see in the following block of code i can access `items.title` but if if want to access `resultData.searchInformation.formattedResults` i get undefined.

```
const items = resultData.items?.map((item)=>{
    return <Item key={item.id} title={item.title} description={item.htmlSnippet}/>
      
      
    }) ?? [] // return an empty array in case the result is undefined
    
  
    

  return (
    <div>
      <input className='searchInput' onChange={handleInputChange} ></input>
      <button className='btn' onClick={searchInGoogle} >Submit</button>
      {/* <Searchbar /> */}
      <div>
        {<p>{resultData.searchInformation.formattedTotalResults}</p>  }

        {
        
        (resultData.items && Object.keys(resultData.items)) !== 0 ? <>
        {items}

        </> : <><p>No results</p></>
        }

      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

`resultData.searchInformation.formattedResults` stand for the amount of results found with the API. So in the first instance is gonna be undefined because there is nothing searched. How can i prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable that verifies if the `resultData.searchInformation` is not empty and if true renders a `<p>` tag with the information, and if false renders an empty `<p>` tag.

const items = resultData.items?.map((item)=>{
return

```
    }) ?? [] // return an empty array in case the result is undefined
  
  const searchInfo = resultData.searchInformation ? <p>{resultData.searchInformation.formattedResults}</p> : <p></p>
  
    

  return (
    <div>
      <input className='searchInput' onChange={handleInputChange} ></input>
      <button className='btn' onClick={searchInGoogle} >Submit</button>
      {/* <Searchbar /> */}
      <div>
        { (resultData.searchInformation && Object.keys(resultData)) !== 0 ? <>
            {searchInfo}

        </> : <p></p> 
        }

        {
        
        (resultData.items && Object.keys(resultData.items)) !== 0 ? <>
        {items}

        </> : <><p>No results</p></>
        }

      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Search
```